# Distinct by property of class with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a collection:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
```

Cars are uniquely identified by their property `CarCode`.

I have three cars in the collection, and two with identical CarCodes.

How can I use LINQ to convert this collection to Cars with unique CarCodes?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/489258/3258851)

Answer (score 352, accepted):

You can use grouping, and get the first car from each group:

```
List<Car> distinct =
  cars
  .GroupBy(car => car.CarCode)
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I think that no Overhead exists!

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi: There is a bit of overhead, as the groups are created, and then only one item from each group is used.

Comment: for more keys write:  .GroupBy(car =>new{ car.CarCode,car.PID,car.CID})

Comment: instead of First() we should use FirstOrDefault() in this case, since First() can only be used as a final query operation

Comment: @Nani generally speaking you're right, but since a group will only created if there is a matching element in the collection, there will be at least one element per group. --> `First()` is totally okay in this usecase.

Comment: public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, object> propertySelector){
            return enumerable.GroupBy(propertySelector).Select(x => x.First());
        }

Comment: A simple and perfect answer.. keep coding

Comment: .NET 6 has `DistinctBy` now (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 134):

Use [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), which has a `DistinctBy` method :)

```
IEnumerable<Car> distinctCars = cars.DistinctBy(car => car.CarCode);
```

(This is only for LINQ to Objects, mind you.)

Comment: just providing the link!http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307

Comment: Hi Jon, two questions if I may. 1) Why don't you add the library to Nuget? 2) What about LINQ to SQL\EF\NH? how can we implement that? Do we have to use Guffa version(which is your version if `NO_HASHSET` is true...)? Thank you very much!

Comment: @gdoron: 1) It's in NuGet already: http://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq 2) I doubt that LINQ to SQL etc are flexible enough to allow that.

Comment: Ohh, it's prerelease... that's why I couldn't find it. 2) Well I'm afraid adding the Lib to my project, I'm afraid someone will use it with `IQueryable<T>` and try to `DistinctBy` it and thus query the whole God damn table... Isn't it error prone? Thanks again from your extremely quick response!

Comment: @gdoron: No, 2.0 is prerelease - 1.0 isn't. As for whether it's error-prone... well, that's true of LINQ in general, in that you could always pass an `IQueryable<T>` to something expecting `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I tried using MoreLinq for the same task, particularly DistinctBy. It wasn't very efficient at all. The MoreLinq/DistinctBy query made the method take 2.5minutes to execute as per Chrome's network tab, where as the GroupBy approach took 1.5 seconds. I had to convert to Queryable using the AsQueryable method, maybe that had some influence.

Comment: Would you consider it a bad habit to include the MoreLinq features under the `System.Linq` namespace, so no need to add additional usings to each file that wants to access those features?

Comment: @Shimmy: I'd personally feel nervous about writing code under `System` as that gives a false impression of it being "official". But your tastes may vary, of course :)

Comment: @gdoron: Yes, it is. I'll edit the LINQ.

Answer (score 69):

Same approach as Guffa but as an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> property)
{
    return items.GroupBy(property).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

Used as:

```
var uniqueCars = cars.DistinctBy(x => x.CarCode);
```

Comment: Perfect.  This same method is also provided on the Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities library.

Comment: Note that in .NET 6 and .NET 7 Preview a more production ready version is available. See  :
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ebba1d4acb7abea5ba15e1f7f69d1d1311465d16/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Distinct.cs
This includes both deferred execution and proper error handling. Code above is simplistic compared to the different scenarios that might occur including error conditions.

Answer (score 33):

You can implement an IEqualityComparer and use that in your Distinct extension.

```
class CarEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Car> Members

    public bool Equals(Car x, Car y)
    {
        return x.CarCode.Equals(y.CarCode);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Car obj)
    {
        return obj.CarCode.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then

```
var uniqueCars = cars.Distinct(new CarEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: How can we use this without writting : new CarEqualityComparer() ?

Comment: @Parsa You can create an IEqualitiyComparer wrapper type that accepts lambdas. This would make it generalized: `cars.Distinct(new GenericEqualityComparer<Car>((a,b) => a.CarCode == b.CarCode, x => x.CarCode.GetHashCode()))`. I've used such in the past as it sometimes adds value when performing a one-off Distinct.

Answer (score 12):

Another extension method for Linq-to-Objects, without using GroupBy:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the set of items, made distinct by the selected value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The source collection.</param>
    /// <param name="selector">A function that selects a value to determine unique results.</param>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable&lt;TSource&gt;.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        HashSet<TResult> set = new HashSet<TResult>();

        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            var selectedValue = selector(item);

            if (set.Add(selectedValue))
                yield return item;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the best option in Terms of performance (or in any terms) is to Distinct using the The **IEqualityComparer** interface.

Although implementing each time a new comparer for each class is cumbersome and produces boilerplate code.

So here is an extension method which produces a new **IEqualityComparer** on the fly for any class using reflection.

**Usage:**

```
var filtered = taskList.DistinctBy(t => t.TaskExternalId).ToArray();
```

**Extension Method Code**

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> property)
    {
        GeneralPropertyComparer<T, TKey> comparer = new GeneralPropertyComparer<T,TKey>(property);
        return items.Distinct(comparer);
    }   
}
public class GeneralPropertyComparer<T,TKey> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, TKey> expr { get; set; }
    public GeneralPropertyComparer (Func<T, TKey> expr)
    {
        this.expr = expr;
    }
    public bool Equals(T left, T right)
    {
        var leftProp = expr.Invoke(left);
        var rightProp = expr.Invoke(right);
        if (leftProp == null && rightProp == null)
            return true;
        else if (leftProp == null ^ rightProp == null)
            return false;
        else
            return leftProp.Equals(rightProp);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        var prop = expr.Invoke(obj);
        return (prop==null)? 0:prop.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the reflection here?

Answer (score 1):

You can't effectively use `Distinct` on a collection of objects (without additional work). I will explain why.

[The documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx):

> It uses the default equality comparer, `Default`, to compare values.

For objects that means it uses the default equation method to compare objects ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs)). That is on their hash code. And since your objects don't implement the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals` methods, it will check on the reference of the object, which are not distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish the same thing...

```
List<Car> distinticBy = cars
    .Select(car => car.CarCode)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(code => cars.First(car => car.CarCode == code))
    .ToList();
```

It's possible to create an extension method to do this in a more generic way. It would be interesting if someone could evalute performance of this 'DistinctBy' against the GroupBy approach.

Comment: The second `Select` would be an O(n*m) operation, so that won't scale well. It could perform better if there are a lot of duplicates, i.e. if the result of the first `Select` is a very small part of the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my [PowerfulExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerfulExtensions/) library. Currently it's in a very young stage, but already you can use methods like Distinct, Union, Intersect, Except on any number of properties;

This is how you use it:

```
using PowerfulExtensions.Linq;
...
var distinct = myArray.Distinct(x => x.A, x => x.B);
```

Comment: If i have a list of objects where I want to delete all objects with the same ID's, will it be `myList.Distinct(x => x.ID)` ?