# Convert generic.list<string> to generic list product

Tags: linq, entity-framework

i have code like this :

```
  var list = _appData.GetAdvanceSearchData(Convert.ToInt16(collection["Product"])).ToList();
   List<ProductMaterial> materials = list.Select(x => x.ProductMaterial).Distinct().ToList();
```

Exception I got :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Crescent.LinqModel.ProductMaterial>'
```

whst should be done ?

Product Material Class :

```
 public class ProductMaterial
{
    public string ProductMaterials {get;set;}
}
```

list.Select(x => x.ProductMaterial).Distinct().ToList() gives me array string though have converted to list , i want the result of type 'ProductMaterial'.

Comment: what is the type of `ProductMaterial`? string or a custom class?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
var materials = list.Select(x => x.ProductMaterial).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or:

```
List<string> materials = list.Select(x => x.ProductMaterial).Distinct().ToList();
```

The only thing that is different is the type of the `materials` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs)

```
List<ProductMaterial> materials =
    list.DistinctBy(x => x.ProductMaterial).ToList();
```

You can use that extension method or search for some [other implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537846/340760)

Answer (score 0):

The query `list.Select(x => x.ProductMaterial).Distinct().ToList();` returns `List<string>` not `List<ProductMaterial>`.

You can use List instead of `List<ProductMaterial>`.
I am not sure about what you want.I could have given a more precise opinion if data type of list was specified.

Comment: @DharaPPatel what is the data type of var list ? if var list is List<ProductMaterials> then you can use **WHERE** instead of **SELECT** to query down distinct entries