# Linq outer join with conditions

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I need an efficient LINQ query (in method syntax if possible) to get all items from a collection A that have no corresponding key 
in a second collection B (1 to n) or if there exist elements in B, take only those that have MyValue  null. In short: return all elements of A that do not exist in B or if they exist in B where at minimum one row has MyValue = null.

```
table A
{
  int MyKey (primary_key);
}

table B
{ 
  int MyKey (foreign_key to A.MyKey);
  string MyValue;
}
```

I was trying Except(), but this only works, when both collections are of the same type.
I was trying GroupJoin(), but I did not find a way how to remove the duplicates after joining.

```
a.GroupJoin(
 b.Where(item => item.Value = null), 
 el => el.MyKey, 
 el2 => el2.MyKey,
 (el3, el4) => el3);
```

With this, I filter out items in B, that are after joined again because they don't exist anymore.

In pure sql it is very easy to achive:

```
select * from A a left join B b on a.MyKey = b.MyKey where MyValue is null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's much prettier in LINQ syntax:

```
var result = (
    from a in aCollection
    join b in bCollection on a.Key equals b.AKey into bSubCollection
    where !bSubCollection.Any(x => x.Value != null)
    select a
);
```

But here it is in method syntax as well:

```
var result = aCollection
    .GroupJoin(bCollection, a => a.Key, b => b.AKey, (a, bSub) => new { a, bSub })
    .Where(c => !c.bSub.Any(x => x.Value != null))
    .Select(c => c.a);
```

Essentially you are group joining into an anonymous type with the `a` and a collection of `b` then just filtering the collection of `c` (`a` is already distinct) by whether there are any `b`s with a non-null `Value`.

Comment: That's it!
I only used "c.bSub.All(x => x.Value == null)"
instead of "!c.bSub.Any(x => x.Value != null))"

Answer (score 0):

you need to translate in method syntax but the query syntax for the left outer join you wrote should be the following:

```
 var query = from itemA in a
        join itemB in b on
            itemA.MyKey equals itemB.MyKey into joinTable
        from itemB in joinTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (itemB == null) || (itemB.MyValue == null)
        select itemA;
```

you need to apply a distinct to the result.
You can see the following post:
[Distinct by property of class by linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-by-linq)

or use DistinctBy in [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)