# select specific rows from datatable using where clause C#

Tags: c#

I have a datatable `dt_Customers` which contains `Customer_ID`, `Email` and some other data. Some of the emails are duplicates in this data table, means they are repeating 2,3 or more times.

I have selected distinct emails in a list by using:

```
List<string> Email = dt_Customers.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Email")).Distinct().ToList();
```

Against these selected Emails which are in the list now. Is it possible to select `Customer_ID` from the data table?

Or I have to write SQL query which will fetch the data from SQL Server database against selected email Ids in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or I have to write SQL query which will fetch the data from SQL Server
>   database against selected email Ids in the list.

No you don't have to fetch them again from the Database, you already have them in your `DataTable`. You can use the following query which would check the Emails list against the `DataTable` in memory, like:

```
List<int> customerIDs = dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(r => Email.Contains(r.Field<string>("Email")))
                            .Select(r => r.Field<int>("Customer_ID"))
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no DistinctBy method in LINQ, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-by-linq) is workaround and custom Extension method

```
var customerIds = dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
                              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Email"))
                              .Select(g => g.First().Field<int>("Customer_ID"))
                              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `Email` then select all `Customer_ID`s from that group:

```
var emails = dt_Customers.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("Email"));
foreach (var emailGroup in emails)
{
    var email = emailGroup.Key;
    var ids = emailGroup.Select(dr => dr.Field<int>("Customer_ID "]));
}
```