# How to aggregate over one property while summing another?

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I have a list of invoices and each record consist of a customer ID and an amount. The aim is to produce a list of payments where each payment is unique per customer (there might be multiple invoices per each customer) and sums the related invoices' amounts to a total.

Producing a list of distinct invoices (with respect to the customer ID) is [very easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-by-linq). The things is that I then only have the value of the first invoice's amount and not the sum.

```
List<Payment> distinct = invoices
  .GroupBy(invoice => invoice.CustomerId)
  .Select(group => group.First())
  .Select(invoice => new Payment
  {
    CustomerId = invoice.CustomerId,
    Total = invoice.Amount
  }).ToList();
```

Is there a smooth LINQ-fu for that or do I need to go *foreach* on my list?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you provided sample input and expected output - along with how far you'd got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have something like this

```
Invoice[] invoices = new Invoice[3];

invoices[0] = new Invoice { Id = 1, Amount = 100 }; 
invoices[1] = new Invoice { Id = 1, Amount = 150 }; 
invoices[2] = new Invoice { Id = 2, Amount = 300 };
```

Then you could have your goal as

```
var results = from i in invoices
              group i by i.Id into g
              select new { Id = g.Key, TotalAmount = g.Sum(i => i.Amount)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of jmelosegui:

```
List<Payment> distinct = invoices
   .GroupBy(c => c.CustomerId)
   .Select(c => new Payment
   {
     CustomerId = c.Key, 
     Total = c.Sum(x => x.Amount)
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: @jmelosegui Awesome, thanks to both. I just realized that it's not going to work, though. The answer to the stated problem itself is valid. Sadly though, I'm getting the error that an instance of entity/complex type *Payment*  cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query... I'm assuming that this is an unrelated issue to the original question and needs to be investigated separately.