# Distinct statement not working as i expected it to

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a table with multiple email addresses from one person - So **EACH** email address is listed several times in this table.

I would like to make it `Distinct` - so every email address is listed one.

My table has a relationship from the Customers table to the Customer Email address collection table

```
Customers.CustomerEmails.Where(Function(e) e.EmailId = EmailID).OrderBy(Function(o) o.CustomerId).Distinct()
```

I added a `Distinct` to the end of the statement but this didn't work. I have added `Distinct` after each method but that doesn't work either.

I then tried to add the order by at a different location in case this is causing some issues but again that didn't help either.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-by-linq where various alternatives are proposed. It is C#, but converting C# LINQ code to VB.NET is quite easy.

Comment: The CustomerEmail entities are different, so the distinct does return them all. You need to select only the emailaddress string and distinct on that...

Comment: So i need to create a List of CustomerEmail and then Distinct on that?