# Select Distinct from list in date range with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class for unassigned work.

```
public class UnassignWork
{
    public int RecordNr { get; set; }
    public string GroupNum { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberID { get; set; }
    public decimal DedAmt { get; set; }
    public decimal CopayCoinsAmt { get; set; }
    public int BaseDed { get; set; }
    public int BaseOOP { get; set; }
    public string ClaimRespCode { get; set; }
    public string ClaimRejCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime VendorFileDate { get; set; }
    public string PackageCd { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClaimDOS { get; set; }
    public string WorkTypeCd { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAssigned { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list based on the class..

```
List<UnassignWork> UnassignedWorkList = new List<UnassignWork>();`
```

How do I get a list of the items in UnassignedWorkList where the VendorFileDate is between startdate and enddate?

```
List<UnassignWork> dateRangeList = new List<UnassignWork>();

dateRangeList = UnassignedWorkList.Select(x=> x.VendorFileDate between startdate and enddate).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to implement a "between" comparison?

Comment: You don't have a start or end date in `UnassignWork` class. Where can they be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.Select()` method is for transforming results. 
To limit results, use `Where()`

You want something like :

```
UnassignedWorkList.Where(x => x.VendorFileDate > startData && x.VendorFileDate < endDate)
```

As noted by CodeNotFound in the comments here, You may actually want to use an inclusive range :

```
UnassignedWorkList.Where(x => x.VendorFileDate >= startData && x.VendorFileDate <= endDate)
```

To make the result distinct, you could use the `Distinct()` method, but that uses the default equality comparer so you'd need to implement the equality operator on your class for that to work ( see - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx). You can implement a your own "DistinctBy" method or just use the `GroupBy()` as an alternative - you can see both approaches here : [Distinct by property of class with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-with-linq)

Comment: SQL "between" include both sides so you should use >= and <=

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);
        var toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);
        var tempList = new List<UnassignWork>();
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned=DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)});
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) });
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2) });
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3) });
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(4) });
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5) });
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(6) });
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7) });
        tempList.Add(new UnassignWork { DateAssigned = DateTime.Today.AddDays(8) });

        //Lambda Operation
        var filterdList = tempList.Where(e => e.DateAssigned >= fromDate && e.DateAssigned <= toDate);

        //Linq Operation
        var filterdList2 = (from t in tempList
                            where t.DateAssigned >= fromDate && t.DateAssigned <= toDate
                            select t);
    }
}
public class UnassignWork
{
    public int RecordNr { get; set; }
    public string GroupNum { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberID { get; set; }
    public decimal DedAmt { get; set; }
    public decimal CopayCoinsAmt { get; set; }
    public int BaseDed { get; set; }
    public int BaseOOP { get; set; }
    public string ClaimRespCode { get; set; }
    public string ClaimRejCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime VendorFileDate { get; set; }
    public string PackageCd { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClaimDOS { get; set; }
    public string WorkTypeCd { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAssigned { get; set; }
}
```