How to remove element whose count > 1 from IEnumerable
I have an IEnumerable and some entries have a duplicate Name. I want to remove those duplicate entries.
For example, if Name is : "Prag1":

First I want to check if there is more than one entry in my  IEnumerable with that name

If yes, then I want to remove one element and want to keep another one


I have tried this but not working for me:
data.ToList().Remove(data.ToList().Find(x => x.Name == "Prag1));

Update: Distinct is not working for me, because in my list there is one more field with name Date and its values are different.
So if in first record in Company1 date is 15-Nov, the second entry's date might be 22-Nov

you can use a custom EqualityComparer and the .Distinct() linq method

This question is similar to: Remove duplicates from a List in C#. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Mushroomator I have added my comments why that question is not helpful to me.

You could almost definitely use DistinctBy. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537846/9852011

If you want pure Linq, you can try DistinctBy:
var list = data
  .DistinctBy(item => item.Name)
  .ToList();

For old .Net versions (which don't provide DistinctBy) you can emulate it with GroupBy:
var list = data
  .GroupBy(item => item.Name)      // For each of groups of items with the same Name  
  .Select(group => group.First())  // we want just first item from the group
  .ToList();

If you want to process existing list you can use HashSet<T> to keep unique Names:
// Initial list with possible duplicate Names
var list = data.ToList(); 

var unique = new HashSet<string>();

int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
    if (unique.Add(list[i].Name))
        list[index++] = list[i];

list.RemoveRange(index, list.Count - index);

